# CSS3 blur filter on HTML body tag

Tags: css, filter, blur

Is it possible to have a `background image` on the `Body`tag, and then add `blur` filter on it, whitout getting the blur effect on the `div's` thats inside the `body` ?

Or do U need to add it on the first `div` inside the `body` as I can see many ex. on ?

Comment: have you tried it out by yourself? When `YES`...please post some code and fiddle what you have tried! Thanks amigo

Comment: Yes i have and need to go back on my other laptop, so i will post fiddle later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS filters, all child elements of the element being blurred will also be blurred. However, rather than clutter your markup with an extra div just for the sake of a bg image with blur, you can use a pseudo element.

Don't forget to give it a z-index below the other content. In this case I just used -1, but you could use any number and give the other elements another number higher.

CSS

```
body:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  background: url(http://hackingui.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/meng2-1980x1000.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[Check it out on codepen](http://cdpn.io/wdGsz)

Comment: Hi DMT u fix it, with the `z-index` and the `background:url` I used `background-image:url`, but I have problems getting `-moz-filter: blur(10px);` to work on firefox, it do not add the blur filter on the image.

Comment: Firefox Does not support CSS filters yet https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browerser_compatibility