# Setting a Grayscale Background Image - Shiny R

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

Tried to use this code in order to apply a grayscale filter to the background image of my R ShinyApp:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style("body {background: url(http://www.katamon.co.il/pics/2014-15/game19Herzeliya/ARL_1787.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
              background-size: cover;
              filter:grayscale(100%);}"),

  headerPanel(fluidRow(column(5,tags$h1(tags$strong("Injury Prevention Data Analysis"),
                               style = "font family:Lobster,cursive;
                                        color:white;background-color:black;
                                        text-align:center;")))),

  fluidRow(
    column(3,offset = 9,
           tags$img(src = "http://www.katamon.co.il/images/logo2015T.png",
                    height = 200,width = 230, align = "right"))),
```

What happens is that it filters the second image only.

Any body knows why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS-related question, the problem is not specific to *R* or *shiny*. The problem in your example script is that the `filter` transformation is applied to *every* child (but not to the `body` it is defined in). Popular solutions focus on [using overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image), which works by defining different CSS classes for background and content, and defining separate HTML elements for each. Another way to achieve the desired effect is to use [CSS pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871333/css3-blur-filter-on-html-body-tag):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(paste0(
      "body:before { ",
      "  content: ''; ",
      "  height: 100%; width: 100%; ",
      "  position: fixed; ",
      "  z-index: -1; ",
      "  background: url(http://www.katamon.co.il/pics/2014-15/game19Herzeliya/ARL_1787.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; ",
      "  background-size: cover; ",
      "  filter: grayscale(100%); ",
      "  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); }"))),
  headerPanel(fluidRow(column(5, tags$h1(
    tags$strong("Injury Prevention Data Analysis"),
    style = "font family:Lobster,cursive;color:white;background-color:black;text-align:center;")))),
  fluidRow(column(3, offset = 9,
    tags$img(src = "http://www.katamon.co.il/images/logo2015T.png",
      height = 200,width = 230, align = "right")))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note the `-webkit-filter` line: While it is redundant on modern browers, the built-in browser of my current installation of RStudio (v0.99.903) requires this to work.

Comment: Thanks! I actually fixed it using this line: filter(url(http://www.katamon.co.il/pics/2014-15/game19Herzeliya/ARL_1787.jpg),grayscale(1)) , but it works in safari, in chrome there is no background image at all when I use this code

Comment: CSS filter _functions_ seem to be more on the cutting edge and may not be as widely supported as filter _properties_ yet. Any reason the proposed solution using the `body:before` pseudo-element does not work for you?